# Jquery: Cycle plugin abruptly stopped working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-cycle

I had a [Cycle](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/) plugin working well on my site until today when a client indicated it was not working. I checked the links to the plugin .js file and to jquery and all is well, but I get the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'cycle'

in my console. I dont understand what could be causing the disconnect.

My code is:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/jqcycle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

$('#frontimageswap') 
.before('<div id="nav">') 
.cycle({ 
    fx:     'turnDown', 
    speed:  'fast', 
    timeout: 5000, 
    pager:  '#nav' 
});
});
</script>
```

Does anyone know what could be causing this?

Comment: did u miss "http:" there ???

Comment: a conflict with another library?

Comment: @bipen thats probably on purpose. so it works with both http: and https:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My fault for not looking properly. There was another jquery library link later on in the page.